# how do i change gridview color based on date asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to add specific colors to the rows of my gridview when specific conditions are met. But the code doesnt work or should i say the effect doesnt show. What i want is - any time the due date which is on the sixth cell exceeds the current date of today or the current date of the system the particular row affected should show give a red background color else it should just show a green background color for the rest of the rows in the gridview.

```
if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
{
    //Check condition here

    DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
    DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

    if(today > date)
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleVioletRed;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleGreen;
    }
```

I have tried searching online for solutions but havent been able to get one.

Comment: Also show the code for the UI part not just the c#.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you had at least posted some of your grid view markup.

In most cases, it is better to grab and use the actual row data source used for binding. Using .cells[] collection is often rendered as markup, and thus the value returned is often not suitable for date time conversions.

For example, if a .cell[] data value is null, then the GridView will render that as "nbsp;". That will cause headaches in attempts to convert as such to a date time.

So, often you can't even check for null, or even use == "" as some string, since the markup for the GridView is messy at best, and at worst will have things like nbsp; for null values.

Turns out you can get and use the actual data source row used for the data binding. NOTE VERY close, that data source is ONLY valid during the binding process. Once data binding is complete, then the data source goes out of scope.

So, this approach tends to work well.

Markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table" 
    Width="45%" OnRowDataBound="GVHotels_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="BookingDate" HeaderText="Booking Date" 
            DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code behind to load the GridView:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
                        ORDER BY HotelName";
        GVHotels.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GVHotels.DataBind();
    }
```

And to conditional color each row, then we use the RowDataBound event.

This code:

```
protected void GVHotels_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
        if (gData["BookingDate"].ToString() == "")
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.PaleVioletRed;   // color for null
        else
        {
            DateTime MyDate = (DateTime)gData["BookingDate"];
            if (MyDate < DateTime.Today)
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSteelBlue;
            else
                e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightSeaGreen;
        }
    }
}
```

And the result is this:

[image]

So, note close how we did NOT use the .cells[] collection, but used the data source of row used for binding that one row.

This also means we can use the column name, and not cells[] collection (this is less error prone if you modify the GridView).

Furthermore, you might want to use a date format string, say only show the weekday, the month, or whatever. However, since we separated the logic of display (the .cells collection) from that of our code logic which operates directly against the data source, then we don't care about formatting issues.
There are a number of ways to test for null, but a simple .ToString() returns a empty string when null, and thus I used .ToString() for my null test in above.